# Bizarre display issues with primary monitor after replacing my video card

Tags: display, troubleshooting

A few weeks ago, I replaced my video card after frying my old one due to poor cable placement after a case rebuild. Ever since, I've had a really weird problem, which is best illustrated by this video that I took of a my screen: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nn3fOzLB5fY (apologies for Tesla homepage. For some reason having it open made the flicker go into overdrive, which is why I recorded the video then)

My main display (but not my second one) seems to be "stuttering" every few seconds. A small band across the screen will flicker for just a moment, before going back to normal. You can see the flickers at 0:03, another at 0:07, and a huge one at 0:09 in the video.

It doesn't seem to occur while I'm gaming, but while I'm browsing with Firefox, it's quite annoyingly frequent. I was previously advised to try replacing the DisplayPort cable, but that sadly didn't help at all.

In addition, I've recently noticed that my monitor looks "dirty": https://i.stack.imgur.com/brmJZ.jpg. I assumed it was actual dirt and tried to clean it off, but nothing I did had any effect. The display seems to be rendering that garbage over top of whatever is displaying on the screen.

Any advice for either of these issues would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my relevant system specs:

- OS: Windows 10 Enterprise
- Previous (fried) video card: GTX 980 Ti
- Current video card: RTX 2070
- CPU: Intel Core i7 6700k 4.00Ghz
- Monitor: Acer Predator XB271HU G-sync monitor (purchased ~3 years ago)
- Motherboard: ASUS Z170-A

And in case it's relevant, I also replaced my power supply at the same time as replacing my video card. Could that have something to do with this?

I have the latest monitor drivers and GPU drivers, and I'm working on installing the latest motherboard drivers now, just in case that'll make a difference.

Comment: Installing the chipset drivers if required should be done before any other drivers. And if you didn't reinstall the OS after such drastic hardware change then all bets are off.

Comment: Is a power supply and video card upgrade really "drastic"? If I'd replaced the mobo, sure, but it was just those two things.

Comment: Windows or Linux can handle much better a motherboard replacement than a graphics card replacement. And both, especially Windows recommend an installation from scratch.

Comment: Wow, really? My past experience is the exact opposite. Not doing a Windows re-install after a mobo upgrade has *always* screwed me, but I've done half a dozen GPU upgrades with nothing besides a graphics driver install.

Comment: But now you're the one with a problem, not me, so...